# Transaction in Laravel rolled back incompletely

Tags: laravel

I have an array of `Organization` model. Each `Organization` contains an array of `User` model.

There is a many-to-many relationship between them using the `OrganizationUser` model.

If I have problems inserting an `Organization`, an `User`, or a relationship between them, I want to roll everything back.

But I also use "try catch" blocks to see at which stage the error occurred.
To test this, I explicitly made a mistake in the `OrganizationUser` relationship object. I'm using an `User` id that can't be in the `Organization`.

This rolls back the `Organization`, relationships, and first `User`, but all other Users are added to the database.

```php
DB::beginTransaction();
$org->save();
foreach ($org->user_list as $user) {
    try {
        $user->save();
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        DB::rollback();
        Log::error('Error user insert : '. $user->inn .' '. $exception->getMessage());
    }

    try {
        $orgs_user = OrganizationUser::create([
            'user_id' => 80,
            'org_id' => $org->id,
        ]);
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        DB::rollback();
        Log::error('Insert user_org relationship : ' . $exception->getMessage());
    }
}
```

When I didn't use the "try catch" block it worked well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `DB::rollBack()` (by the way it's roll**B**ack with a capital **B**), that ***ends*** the transaction. The rest of the queries will execute as normal.

The safest way to use transactions is to put the entire thing in a single try catch. The `\Exception` itself should contain enough information to know what caused it in its message or stack trace.

```php
try {
    DB::beginTransaction();
    $org->save();
    foreach ($org->user_list as $user) {
        $user->save();
        $orgs_user = OrganizationUser::create([
            'user_id' => 80,
            'org_id' => $org->id,
        ]);
    }
    DB::commit();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    DB::rollBack();
}
```

It is a bit verbose, but you can also use the `DB::transaction()` method.

```php
DB::transaction(function () use ($org) {
    $org->save();
    foreach ($org->user_list as $user) {
        $user->save();
        $orgs_user = OrganizationUser::create([
            'user_id' => 80,
            'org_id' => $org->id,
        ]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`DB::rollback` does not stop the execution of the code.

If you are in a `catch` block the transaction will be rolled back but the next block (as well as the rest of the iteration) will continue.

Use a `break;` after the rollback to break out of the loop completely like below:

```php
DB::beginTransaction();
$org->save();
foreach ($org->user_list as $user) {
    try {
        $user->save();
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        DB::rollback();
        Log::error('Error user insert : '. $user->inn .' '. $exception->getMessage());
        break;
    }

    try {
        $orgs_user = OrganizationUser::create([
            'user_id' => 80,
            'org_id' => $org->id,
        ]);
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        DB::rollback();
        Log::error('Insert user_org relationship : ' . $exception->getMessage());
        break;
    }
}
```

You can also `return;` or just `exit()` depending on how you want to handle the error